# Libraries installed but didn't work in react-native environment

Tags: react-native, native-base

Anytime I install Library, whether it is, native base or react-native text-input effects.it gives the same error every time..
I don't know what's causing an issue here.

```
 error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module 
native-base`   from file `/home/jas/Hopper/screen/Home.js`, the package ` 
/home/jas/Hopper /node_modules/native-base/package.json` was successfully 
found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that  
could not be resolved (`/home/jas/Hopper/node_modules/native-base/dist
/src/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

Comment: Is the error correct?  Does the package.json from native-base specify a file that isn't actually there?

Comment: @ArtHare what does that suppose to mean? Btw error is correct..what's missing here?

Comment: You can go digging on your filesystem and see if /home/jas/Hopper/node_modules/native-base/dist/src/index.js actually doesn't exist.  That may give more clues as to what is screwing up.

Comment: How do you install the libraries?

Comment: @ArtHare yes index.js exists

Comment: @Stophface I installed libraries by npm

Answer (score 1):

Delete the build folder in /node_modules/native-base/android/app